# Do conditions for conversion stand legitimate in front of Allah?

Tags: conversion

I am a new Muslim who has not officially converted to Islam. I live with my family and they are very hostile against Muslims, therefore neither can I convert while living with them or can offer Salat if I convert covertly. Thus even though I have accepted Islam I wish to convert effectively after I move out. Is this possible? I also do this because I wish to make myself infallible by the time I move out, which as it stands today is not an easy road.

This decision should depend on me pragmatically, however what got me to thinking was since my dua's have been accepted, I believe I am Muslim in front of Allah and as my dua's are accepted so will my sins count, some of which like zina which occur rather occasionally though far less than before might constitute a major sin.

Answer (score 1):

You are a Muslim, there is no "official" channel or process to become a Muslim. Simple saying the Shahada and believing in it, even without the knowledge of anyone else makes you a Muslim in the eyes of Allah -However, that won't get you Islamic treatment from the Public.

It is all about your intention. If publically proclaiming your new religion will hurt you physically or will get you thrown out of your house, I say keep it in your heart. Allah says in the holy quran:

[image]

> Whoever disbelieves in Allah after his belief... except for one who is forced [to renounce his religion] while his heart is secure in faith... [16:106]

This not only gives you permission not to practice Islam, but even renounce Islam if needed. This applies to people who are afraid of death, have harm inflected on them or in dire situation like yours.

[Also many scholars agree that you will not have to make up for missing Prayers/Fasting during such phase](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/146651). If you die you will die a Muslim inshala.

Finally, you said: `some of which like zina which occur rather occasionally though far less than`. I don't clearly understand this. Is Adultery forced upon you from your family? I know many Christian, Jews, Atheists who sustain from sex for various reasons. I do not see how or why you would still commit Zina after believing in Allah and know he doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you die before "officially converting"? There is no such a thing infallible. Any Muslim can become a non-Muslim with just 1 wrong claim. It is a life-long struggle which will be repeated every single moment. A Muslim should be careful and conscious in his/her life except sleep.

Postponing is not good logically. You can think that it is a homework which you don't know the deadline (delivery time). You may thing "I will do it tomorrow", but tomorrow may be too late for that. Nobody can be sure that s/he will live 5 more minutes.

**EDIT:** Look, if you have accept Islam, then you are a Muslim, which means the same rules and responsibilities for all Muslims are on you too. If you do a forbidden thing, this would be sin. If you don't fulfill your religious duties, your debts would count. You may not be able to do all of your duties, but as soon as you are available, you should pay your past debts too. Being nice against parents is very important even if your parents are non-Muslim. But religious duties are more important. You should try to convince them about praying salat etc are not harmful to anyone. Until then, you should try to find some temporary solutions to fulfill your duties.